# How to enable extensions when in read-only mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, readonly

My team is working on an extension that leverages the Github Pull Request Review functionality (which puts the code into a READ ONLY mode).

Is there a way to enable other extensions when in this mode?